# SQL How to sum from another table and insert in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For now I sum in `Delphi` app and then insert it in `SQL` database
but I want database to sum and insert automatically when I insert new `ExpenseAmount`
I have 2 tables

```
ProjectsTable (ProjectID, ProjectName, Cost, ExpenseTotal, CostRemaining)
ExpenseTable (ID, ProjectID, ExpenseAmount, ExpenseDate)
```

I want automatically sum `ExpenseAmount` for every single project in `ProjectsTable` and insert it in `ExpenseTotal` from `ProjectsTable`
I want to do that in `SQL` all out of `Delphi`

Comment: What Sql to do what you want have you written so far?  Please add it to your q.

Comment: I don't use sql to sum I sum in Delphi then insert it like other fields

Comment: Note that it's generally considered bad practice to store data easily derived from other data.

Comment: Then you need to learn it.  You shold know by now that SO isn't a code-writing service, and that includes Sql code.

Comment: @Strawberry so it's better to sum in Delphi and then insert it in table? or what you can suggest for me?

Comment: @MartynA I didn't ask to write code for me, I just don't know the right way to do it and just want to find the best and safest way to do it, so I don't lose data or have some problems in my database later

Comment: Then do some googling; there are hundreds of online Sql tutorials available.

Comment: I did already, and I found few ways like GROUP BY and INNER JOIN and use SUM with SELECT, but I don't know what the easiest and best and fastest way, that why I ask this question.

Comment: It's generally better not to store data that is easily derived from other data. How you derive it is (fairly) irrelevant (although if I was to calculate it, then I guess I'd do it in SQL)

Comment: You mean I calculate it in run time and show it in the table, isn't that will slow when you have much rows to calculate, and it will automatically update the calculated cell in selected row when I insert new ExpenseAmount or it will calculate for all rows again?

Comment: I'm talking about 10000 projects or more and every project have between 4 to 10 ExpenseAmount, so I don't want to calculate the sum for 10000 projects when only one projects is updated, I think it will be slow?

Comment: I removed the Delphi-related tags, because this question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi. It's a completely SQL related question. Please don't use tags on your questions that don't apply to the matter at hand. The fact you're using Delphi for your UI has zero bearing on the topic you're asking about here. Tags used should be **relevant** to the question being asked.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry my mistake, thanks for remove it and remind me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this trigger to your ExpenseTable

```
CREATE TRIGGER ExpenseSum AFTER INSERT ON ExpenseTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ProjectsTable P
    SET ExpenseTotal = 
    (SELECT SUM(ExpenseAmount) from ExpenseTable
    where ExpenseTable.ProjectID= P.ProjectID)
    where P.ProjectID = New.ProjectID;
END
```

Don't forget to add trigger **`After Update`** and **`After Delete`** to update ExpenseTotal

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I want, yes I will add trigger after update and after delete

Answer (score 2):

You can create a subquery grouping the expense amount for each project, and then updating the Projects table.

```
UPDATE ProjectsTable
SET ProjectsTable.ExpenseTotal = S1.ExpenseAmount
FROM ProjectsTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT ProjectID, SUM(ExpenseAmount) as ExpenseAmount
FROM ExpenseTable
GROUP BY ProjectID) as S1
ON ProjectsTable.ProjectID = S1.ProjectID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but I want to find a way to do that in MySQL database without using subquery, I will accept it if didn't find that.

Comment: @DelphiLover What's your objection to subqueries? Aesthetic, emotional, religious?

Comment: @Strawberry I don't have any objection, I just want to do all that in SQL database without using Delphi, and is this the best way to it?

Comment: @DelphiLover the above TSQL script will update all projects. You may want to add a WHERE clause by ProjectID.
WHERE ProjectsTable.ProjectID = yourProjectIdVariable

There is algo another way, you can use a trigger on the Expenses table. Honestly I'm not a fan of that but will accomplish not executing the tsql script from Delphi.

Comment: Thanks again, you already helped me, I was wondering if Trigger can do it because I never used it before, now this is good point to start, but I don't know if Triggers can make problem in database or not, and if Trigger will calculate sum for all rows or only effected row?

Comment: Yes, a trigger will do the work however keep in mind that it's not the preferred choice for many people. Since you will calculate the ExpenseTotal for the Projects table on any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE on the ExpenseTable, a calculation based on the projectID will do just fine.

Comment: Yes, I still confused what to use for calculate it, but I will try trigger even I still didn't find out how to do it

Comment: Ok, if you need help I think the best approach should be to create a new question regarding triggers and clode this one. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: thank you very much you helped me so much and I already used trigger and it works find